# Re-tagging duplicate images in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm asking on behalf of my father, who is a photographer, but a little bit of a technophobe. He says his clients put tagging information on low-res versions of his images, then sends them back to him and he has to go through and re-tag all the high-res images (all the same filenames - or I imagine with similar prefix/suffixes).

Coming from a programming background this seems like the perfect opportunity for automation - but I don't have particularly good Photoshop skills so I thought I'd put it to the SO community.

How would I go about automating the process of re-tagging higher-res images with the same meta data as the low-res?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how may images we are talking about (tens, hundreds or thousands) and the metaddata can be quite extensive or just simply one or two tags.

You might consider writing a script to copy the information from one to another. You can add the data simply with the following script:

```
var MDDocumentTitle = "my photo";
var MDAuthor = "Joe Bloggs";


addImageData()

// function ADD IMAGE DATA() 
function addImageData()
{
  app.activeDocument.info.title = MDDocumentTitle
  app.activeDocument.info.author = MDAuthor
}
```

Reading the data is bit trickier. But you might be able to do this by saving out a metadata template as an action.